# How this Excel Formula worked?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using following formula to extract the records from the database in excel.

> {=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$11,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$11=$C$1,ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(E$2:E2))),"")}

I got this formula idea from the following YouTube tutorial,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jcqN3swdW8

Now my question is I want to understand the part of the Formula.

here is that,

> "IF($A$2:$A$11=$C$1"

How did the above part work with excel formula? I have tried to use this part individually to return the boolean value from the table but it gives the wrong result every time.

anyone can clear my concept?

Comment: Seems that you should familiarize yourself with array formulas https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle: Yup, I was missing that because I have started learning excel advance directly using VBA, so, whenever I used to need kind of information from the database, I used to with VBA that's why my concept with array formulas are left behind. but thank you so much I have finally cleared it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is turned out to be a very easy concept. Thank you to @TomJohnRiddle for his comment.

I have started learning Advance Excel from VBA. I used to apply VBA literally for every little data processing. Maybe that's why I have never interacted with Excel's Array Formulas. but it's all cleared now

here is the link as Tom has suggested.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Thank you.